# Transitioning from c locrian to c major

Tags: piano

Does anybody know how to transition from **c locrian** to **c major** in two beats on piano?

This is my first question and it is very important to me, so I would be very grateful if someone could answer me as soon as possible.

Comment: It would be helpful to have some context. Perhaps a couple of measures on either side of where the transition needs to be?

Comment: I don't have the full context right now, but I know it has c major and a minor before

Comment: Understood. Just know, to get the most effective responses, the more information you can provide the better. Is this one hand or two? Chords, arpeggios, scales, something else? Tempo? How long has C Locrian been in force? Long enough to truly establish the mode, or just a brief visit? All of these factors can influence how the transition might be made.

Comment: C Locrian is an unusual, and tricky mode in which to write music. Since you need to move to a parallel key, and Locrian is pretty dissonant, why not be simple in the writing, and just go straight to key C? A breath of fresh air!

Comment: I sounds like you have an abrupt key change from Db maj to C maj, based on the modes you mentioned.  And the answer is all you can do, just stop playing one and start playing the other.  If on the other hand you are asking about clever leading tones from one key to the next... they are all a 1/2 step away.  Context would be necessary for provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stop playing in C Locrian and start playing in C major.  Is that too simple?

I wonder if your 'C Locrian' is really a ♭5 substitution for G7? (Or - looked at another way - a G7(alter everything) chord?)

[image]